# React Router - render function - React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I'm new to React Testing library and facing some challenges in writing the test case for render function in React router.
I'm unsure to get the code coverage for the render function of Route. Can some one guide me in that.

```
<Route path="/employee" render={() => <div><h4>Employee Page</h4></div>} />
```

App.test.js

```
it('should render Employee Page', () => {
    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/employee']}>
          <App/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('Employee Page')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

App.js

```
<Router>
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li><NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/article">Article</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/employee">Employee</NavLink></li>
      </ul> 
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/home"  render={() => <div><h4>Home 
            Page</h4></div>} />
         <Route path="/article"  render={() => <div><h4>Article 
            Page</h4></div>} />
         <Route path="/employee" render={() => <div><h4>Employee 
            Page</h4></div>} />
      </Switch>
   </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current test look like?

Comment: I tried the above added test case using React Testing library.
I'm using render function of react route for inline rendering.
My test case is getting success, but unable to get code coverage for render function in Route.

Comment: Can you please add the full code for your `App` component?

Comment: I completed the unit testing and updated the respective code snippets. Apologize my late reply here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I successfully completed the unit testing of React Router and got the code coverage of render function of Route.

App.test.js

```
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';

it('should render Employee', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory(["/", "/employee"])
    history.push('/employee');
    const component = <Router history={history}>
                        <NavLink to="/employee">Employee</NavLink>
                        <App/>
                      </Router>
    render(component);
});
```